# unable to set path of file

Tags: c#, filepath, windows-forms-designer

I have a file in the root folder of my windows form project.How to set the path of this file so that after the installation of project on some other computer the path should not break.

I have tried the following code but it didn't work:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"barcodeForSingleProduct.rpt");
crystal.Load(path);
```

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3RYj.jpg)

Comment: AFAIK that should be good provided that your rpt file is in the same location where you load your assembly.

Comment: If it doesn't work, there should be an exception, please provide the exception information.

You can replace **Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()** with **Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()** and try if it works for you.

Comment: You are not going to deploy your project to the user's machine, so this is not what you actually want.  Select the .rpt file and set its "Copy To Output Directory" property to "Copy if newer".  So it gets copied to the build directory, along with the EXE file.  Find it back at runtime with Application.StartupPath

Comment: The exception thrown is:CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException: 'Load report failed.'

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code for getting your starting path of application dynamiclly

```
var executingFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below Code is Just Sample:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string path = "C:\\images\\universe.jpg";
        // Get directory name.
        string result = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

        Console.WriteLine("PATH:      {0}", path);
        Console.WriteLine("DIRECTORY: {0}", result);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

> PATH:      C:\images\universe.jpg
>
> DIRECTORY: C:\images